# Iterate through several objects form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

Executive Summary

1. **Goal:** I am creating an admin dashboard, editable by a form_for
2. I have a Post model which has two attributes: Subject and Title
3. I have created an Admin Controller, which has an index action
4. I get an error claiming it can't find the undefined method
   `subject' for ActionView:FormBuilder:0x000000031e02c8>
5. Clearly I have a 'subject' item! I am staring at it right now... and cursing.

Dear Friends,

As you can see I have within my post.title, post.subject; I iterate through each @posts.each and then pass each individual object a form! What gives it claims i don't have an item. This is so strange?

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :title, :subject

end
```

routes:

```
resources :admin_dashboards
```

admin_dashboards_controller.rb

```
class AdminDashboardsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all()
  end
```

View: index.html.erb

```
<tr>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= form_for post do |single_post| %>
<td> <%= single_post.subject %> </td>
<td> <%= single_post.submit %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

scheme.rb

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "subject"
    t.text     "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Please show your ```Post``` model, models/post.rb

Comment: Also, on line 2 of your index page, you should use ```<%``` not ```<%=```

Comment: class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :title, :subject
 
end

Comment: Post it in the question for clarity

Comment: msergeant has answered your question. form_for yields a FormBuilder not a Post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter of the form_for block is not post, it is a FormBuilder. Try something like this:

```
<tr>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= form_for post do |single_post| %>
      <td> <%= single_post.text_field :subject %> </td>
      <td> <%= single_post.submit %> </td>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>   
</tr>
```

Comment: Those hours have not been wasted if you learned something. You'll never make that specific mistake again :)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I hope I can return the favor back to the community when I am less horrible. I am disappointed at such a silly mistake.